# 'Crunching' error working with huge images on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I'm creating a site that has the possibility of drag a huge image resolution (6000x8000 72dpi saved for web, approx 2MB) on Angular+WP. The image upload but gives me an error and the crunch doesn't work and I need an intermediate size to show on other pages and the thumb to manage the back...any idea what's wrong?

I have tried the following:

1
Changed the values of my php.ini (on local and remote server)

```
memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 900
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 24M
```

2
Created .htaccess on wp-admin with

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

3
Changed from ImageMagic to GD system

4
Checked folder permissions to be at 755

Thanks

Comment: @jurgemaister it show 'http error' uploading but when I refresh I have the image in the media but with no thumbnail, and when I try to generate with a plugin like regenerate it get stocked

Comment: Please put your full error, and possible stack trace in the question.

Comment: @jurgemaister this is the exact text "There has been an error. Please try again later" It's that what you mean???

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/hsabp9sqb/Captura_de_pantalla_2014_12_19_a_las_18_51_40.png

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it!
I was thinking that Imagemagik could be the problem and was the opposite, I had the GD library active so when I finally installed Imagemagik on the server and configure + the php.ini new values it let me upload big images and resize them automatically.